# What is the relationship between steps and epochs in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am going through TensorFlow [get started tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started). In the `tf.contrib.learn` example, these are two lines of code:

```
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
```

I am wondering what is the difference between argument `steps` in the call to `fit` function and `num_epochs` in the `numpy_input_fn` call. Shouldn't there be just one argument? How are they connected?

I have found that code is somehow taking the `min` of these two as the number of steps in the toy example of the tutorial.

At least, one of the two parameters either `num_epochs` or `steps` has to be redundant. We can calculate one from the other. Is there a way I can know how many steps (number of times parameters get updated) my algorithm actually took?

I am curious about which one takes precedence. And does it depend on some other parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between steps and epochs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**TL;DR**: An epoch is when your model goes through your whole training data once. A step is when your model trains on a single batch (or a single sample if you send samples one by one). Training for 5 epochs on a 1000 samples 10 samples per batch will take 500 steps.

The `contrib.learn.io` module is not documented very well, but it seems that `numpy_input_fn()` function takes some numpy arrays and batches them together as input for a classificator. So, the number of epochs probably means "how many times to go through the input data I have before stopping". In this case, they feed two arrays of length 4 in 4 element batches, so it will just mean that the input function will do this at most a 1000 times before raising an "out of data" exception. The steps argument in the estimator `fit()` function is how many times should estimator do the training loop. This particular example is somewhat perverse, so let me make up another one to make things a bit clearer (hopefully).

Lets say you have two numpy arrays (samples and labels) that you want to train on. They are a 100 elements each. You want your training to take batches with 10 samples per batch. So after 10 batches you will go through all of your training data. That is one epoch. If you set your input generator to 10 epochs, it will go through your training set 10 times before stopping, that is it will generate at most a 100 batches.

Again, the io module is not documented, but considering how other input related APIs in tensorflow work, it should be possible to make it generate data for unlimited number of epochs, so the only thing controlling the length of training are going to be the steps. This gives you some extra flexibility on how you want your training to progress. You can go a number of epochs at a time or a number of steps at a time or both or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still do not fully understand the steps parameter in fit. By saying "how many times should estimator do the training loop" you mean how many times the estimator goes over all training set? Let's say we have 1000 training instances, if steps = 10 it mean the estimator will be trained on 10.000 instances?

Comment: No, one training step is one iteration of gradient descent learning algorithm. Since nobody uses plain gradient descent anymore, it will be some sort of  stochastic variation of it, so the input for it will be a batch, not a single item. In your example the batch is 4 training examples. So with a 1000 steps it will train on a 1000 batches of 4.

Comment: and when the batch_size is not defined like in [text_classification.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py), but steps is 100 (in fit). It means it runs gradient descent 100 times after each training on the entire training set?

Comment: In this particular example, yes, all of the training data is used at each step. I am not 100% on this, I am not very familiar with text classification models, but it definitely looks that way.

In a more general sense, you need to look at how the inputs are configured in the model, sometimes there is an obvious batching mechanism and sometimes there isn't. Any mention of epochs generally points towards training based on either batches or individual training samples. When your whole training data is used on every step, each step is essentially an epoch :)

Answer (score 24):

Epoch: One pass through the entire data.

Batch size: The no of examples seen in one batch.

If there are 1000 examples and the batch size is 100, then there will be 10 steps per epoch.

The Epochs and batch size completely define the number of steps.

steps_cal = (no of ex / batch_size) * no_of_epochs

```
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn)
```

If you just write the above code, then the value of 'steps' is as given by 'steps_cal' in the above formula.

```
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps  = steps_less)
```

If you give a value(say 'steps_less') less than 'steps_cal', then only 'steps_less' no of steps will be executed.In this case, the training will not cover the entire no of epochs that were mentioned.

```
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps  = steps_more)
```

If you give a value(say steps_more) more than steps_cal, then also 'steps_cal' no of steps will be executed.

Answer (score 19):

Let's start the opposite the order:

1) ***Steps*** - number of times the training loop in your learning algorithm will run to update the parameters in the model. In each loop iteration, it will process a chunk of data, which is basically a batch. Usually, this loop is based on the *Gradient Descent* algorithm.

2) ***Batch size*** - the size of the chunk of data you feed in each loop of the learning algorithm. You can feed the **whole** data set, in which case the batch size is equal to the data set size.You can also feed **one** example at a time. Or you can feed some number *N* of examples.

3) ***Epoch*** - the number of times you run over the data set extracting batches to feed the learning algorithm.

Say you have 1000 examples. Setting batch size = 100, epoch = 1 and steps = 200 gives a process with one pass (one epoch) over the entire data set. In each pass it will feed the algorithm a batch with 100 examples. The algorithm will run 200 steps in each batch. In total, 10 batches are seen. If you change the epoch to 25, then it will do this 25 times, and you get 25x10 batches seen altogether.

**Why do we need this?** There are many variations on gradient descent (batch, stochastic, mini-batch) as well as other algorithms for optimizing the learning parameters (e.g., L-BFGS). Some of them need to see the data in batches, while others see one datum at a time. Also, some of them include random factors/steps, hence you might need multiple passes on the data to get good convergence.

Comment: In your example, if I change the epoch, I will get 25x10, namely 250, batches. But with steps = 200, there are actually only 200 training loops each of which one batch is fed to. Am I understanding right about that?

Comment: Inside an epoch, the model is updated for each batch. Therefore, the batch_size determines steps already. Its still not clear to me why there is a separate variable 'steps'.

Answer (score 14):

This answer is based on the experimentation I have done on the getting started tutorial code.

Mad Wombat has given a detailed explanation of the terms *num_epochs*, *batch_size* and *steps*. This answer is an extension to his answer.

*num_epochs* - The maximum number of times the program can iterate over the entire dataset in one `train()`. Using this argument, we can restrict the number of batches that can be processed during execution of one `train()` method.

*batch_size* - The number of examples in a single batch emitted by the *input_fn*

*steps* - Number of batches the `LinearRegressor.train()` method can process in one execution

*max_steps* is another argument for `LinearRegressor.train()` method. This argument defines the maximum number of steps (batches) can process in the `LinearRegressor()` objects lifetime.

Let's whats this means. The following experiments change two lines of the code provided by the tutorial. Rest of the code remains as is.

**Note: For all the examples, assume the number of training i.e. the length of *x_train* to be equal to 4.**

**Ex 1:**

`input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=2, shuffle=True)`

`estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=10)`

In this example, we defined the *batch_size* = 4 and *num_epochs* = 2. So, the `input_fn` can emit just 2 batches of input data for one execution of `train()`. Even though we defined *steps* = 10, the `train()` method stops after 2 steps.

Now, execute the `estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=10)` again. We can see that 2 more steps have been executed. We can keep executing the `train()` method again and again. If we execute `train()` 50 times, a total of 100 steps have been executed.

**Ex 2:**

`input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=2, num_epochs=2, shuffle=True)`

`estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=10)`

In this example, the value of *batch_size* is changed to 2 (it was equal to 4 in Ex 1). Now, in each execution of `train()` method, 4 steps are processed. After the 4th step, there are no batches to run on. If the `train()` method is executed again, another 4 steps are processed making it a total of 8 steps.

Here, the value of *steps* doesn't matter because the `train()` method can get a maximum of 4 batches. If the value of *steps* is less than (*num_epochs* x *training_size*) / *batch_size*, see ex 3.

**Ex 3:**

`input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=2, num_epochs=8, shuffle=True)`

`estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=10)`

Now, let *batch_size* = 2, *num_epochs* = 8 and *steps* = 10. The `input_fn` can emit a total of 16 batches in one run of `train()` method. However, *steps* is set to 10. This means that eventhough `input_fn` can provide 16 batches for execution, `train()` must stop after 10 steps. Ofcourse, `train()` method can be re-executed for more steps cumulatively.

---

From examples 1, 2, & 3, we can clearly see how the values of *steps*, *num_epoch* and *batch_size* affect the number of steps that can be executed by `train()` method in one run.

The *max_steps* argument of `train()` method restricts the total number of steps that can be run cumulatively by `train()`

**Ex 4:**

If *batch_size* = 4, *num_epochs* = 2, the `input_fn` can emit 2 batches for one `train()` execution. But, if `max_steps` is set to 20, no matter how many times `train()` is executed only 20 steps will run in optimization. This is in contrast to example 1, where the optimizer can run to 200 steps if the `train()` method is exuted 100 times.

Hope this gives a detailed understanding of what these arguments mean.

Answer (score 3):

num_epochs: the maximum number of epochs (seeing each data point).

steps: the number of updates (of parameters).

You can update multiple times in an epoch
when the batch size is smaller than the number of training data.