# TensorFlow: Correct way of using steps in Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am currently using TensorFlow tutorial's `first_steps_with_tensor_flow.ipynb`  notebook to learn TF for implementing ML models. In the notebook, they have used Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) to optimize the loss function. Below is the snippet of the `my_input_function`:

`def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):`

Here, it can be seen that the batch_size is 1. The notebook uses a housing data set containing 17000 labeled examples for training. This means for SGD, I will be having 17000 batches.

`LRmodel = linear_regressor.train(input_fn = lambda:my_input_fn(my_feature, 
           targets), steps=100)`

I have three questions -

1. Why is `steps=100` in `linear_regressor.train` method above? Since we have 17000 batches and `steps` in ML means the count for evaluating one batch, in `linear_regressor.train` method `steps = 17000` should be initialized, right?
2. Is number of batches equal to the number of steps/iterations in ML?
3. With my 17000 examples, if I keep my `batch_size=100`, `steps=500`, and `num_epochs=5`, what does this initialization mean and how does it correlate to 170 batches?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816124/steps-vs-num-epochs-in-tensorflow-getting-started-tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs-in-tensorflow

Answer (score -1):

step is the literal meaning: means you refresh the parameters in your batch size; so for linear_regessor.train, it will train 100 times for this batch_size 1.
epoch means to refresh the whole data, which is 17,000 in your set.