# what is the difference between num_epochs and steps?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

In tensorflow get started code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)
```

I know what batch_size means, but what do num_epochs and steps mean respectively when there are only 4 training examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between steps and epochs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs. You might find a well-explained answer there.

Comment: Also, check out the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Trainable

Comment: Thanks. It does help a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An epoch means using the whole data you have.

A step means using a single batch data.

So, `n_steps = Number of data in single epoch // batch_size`.

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Trainable,

- steps: Number of steps for which to train model. If None, train forever. 'steps' works incrementally. If you call two times fit(steps=10) then training occurs in total 20 steps. If you don't want to have incremental behaviour please set max_steps instead. If set, max_steps must be None.
- batch_size: minibatch size to use on the input, defaults to first dimension of x. Must be None if input_fn is provided.

Comment: It makes sense, but what about num_epochs here? There are only 4 examples in total.

Comment: I try different values for num_epochs and steps and I find that steps cannot be larger than num_epochs. Maybe num_epochs is the upper bound of training times and steps is the actual training times. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`num_epochs` indicates how many times will the `input_fn` return the whole batch

and `steps` indicates how many times the function should run.

For the method of the object `estimator` here, it will stop either it run more than "steps" times or the `input_fn` ceases to provide data, as according to [Tensorflow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor):

> For each step, calls input_fn, which returns one batch of data. Evaluates until: - steps batches are processed, or - input_fn raises an end-of-input exception (OutOfRangeError or StopIteration).