# WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring detection with image id despite true config parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard, nvidia-docker

I am currently trying to train Faster RCNN Inception V2 model (pre-trained with COCO) with GTSDB dataset. I have the FullIJCNN dataset and I divided the dataset into three part as **training**, **validation** and **test**. Lastly I've created 3 different csv files respectively and then created TFRecord files for *train* and *validation*. On the other hand, I have a code block that reads ground truth box coordinates with respect to each image and draws boxes around traffic signs on the image. Also it writes class labels correctly. Here is a few examples. **Again, these boxes are not predicted by a network. They drawn manually by a function.**

[Drawn Boxes 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O18oP.jpg)

[Drawn Boxes 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzIN0.jpg)

Then I have created a label file using the README file included in the dataset folder and added **0 background** line to first line of the labels.txt to make it work with my code (I think this was some stupid thing to do) because it was throwing *out of index error*. However there is no key for "background" in my .pbtxt file to make it start from 1. Lastly I've configured the **faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config** file, changed `num_classes: 90` to `num_classes: 43` since dataset has 43 classes, `num_examples: 5000` to `num_examples: 186` since I've divided the dataset to have 186 test examples. Used `num_steps: 200000` as it is. Lastly I've started the training job by running

```
python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=50000 \
    --num_eval_steps=2000 \
    --alsologtostderr
```

command and this is the traceback (sorry for code block, I don't know how to add logs specifically):

```
import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function model_fn at 0x7fc4cd6a4938>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/models/research/object_detection/core/box_predictor.py:407: calling reduce_mean (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py:2037: get_or_create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.get_or_create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/models/research/object_detection/core/losses.py:317: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See @{tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2}.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:100: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
2018-07-26 09:48:21.785041: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-07-26 09:48:21.923329: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 9b2f:00:00.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2018-07-26 09:48:21.923382: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-07-26 09:48:22.153991: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-07-26 09:48:22.154053: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2018-07-26 09:48:22.154075: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2018-07-26 09:48:22.154333: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10763 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 9b2f:00:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2018-07-26 09:58:31.794649: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-07-26 09:58:31.794723: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-07-26 09:58:31.794747: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2018-07-26 09:58:31.794765: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2018-07-26 09:58:31.794884: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10763 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 9b2f:00:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring ground truth with image id 2066941970 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring detection with image id 2066941970 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring ground truth with image id 2013299735 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring detection with image id 2013299735 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring ground truth with image id 1416415107 since it was previously added
```

It created lots of warnings like this:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring ground truth with image id 2013299735 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring detection with image id 2013299735 since it was previously added
```

The reason of these messages is `num_examples` has been set to `2000` despite my original config file has the line `num_examples: 186`. I don't understand why it is creating a new config file with different parameter. However after the whole log full of those messages, it gives a report but I can't be sure what this is exactly trying to tell me. Here is the report:

```
creating index...
index created!
creating index...
index created!
Running per image evaluation...
Evaluate annotation type *bbox*
DONE (t=0.07s).
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=0.02s).
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
```

Lastly I've checked Tensorboard to make sure it is training correctly but what I see is frustrating. Here is a screenshot of Tensorboard graphs of my model (loss):

[Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihIMJ.png)

[General Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGrHQ.png)

I feel like I am doing something wrong. I don't know if this is a specific question or not but I tried to give detail as possible as much.

My questions are: What changes should I make in these steps? Why my function draws true boxes but my model can't figure out what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you were able to solve this issue as I am having the exact same problem. Thanks.

Comment: @AbdulJabbar Hi, did you try out GuyTraveler's suggestion? I didn't go that way to train my object detection model so I don't know if that would solve this problem but it makes sense. I suggest you to try out that solution. I would be happy if you let me know about progress you will get.

Comment: I am training a Tensorflow Object Detection model api with custom dataset. In tensorboard images section, I could see Bounding boxes for Ground Truth, but none of detected images have Bounding Boxes. I also got similar kind of curves in tensorboard and Average Precision and Recall in logs are either 0 or -1 (Same as log @DorukSonmez has pasted). Could someone help me resolving this.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you are receiving the warnings is because items from your dataset are being evaluated multiple times. The values you specify for num_train_steps and num_eval_steps should correlate to your train_config batch_size and the size of your dataset. For example if your batch size is 24 and you have 24000 training records the num_train_steps should be set to 1000 and likewise the same calculation method for num_eval_steps but with the number of evaluation records. The model_main.py script does not seem to be leveraging the values you specify in your pipeline.config file if you execute the script with those values specified.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Since I have 849 training and 186 validation images, I've set `batch_size: 1`, `num_steps: 849` and `num_examples: 186` in my pipeline.config. Then I'm starting the training job with `python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=849 \
    --num_eval_steps=186 \
    --alsologtostderr`, TF trains it under 1 minute and this is normal. But I am still getting that errors but less this time.

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me. Any other Idea?

Comment: If your problem is related to the original question then my answer should be sufficient. I would double-check your configuration and that when executing the training script you are specifying the correct path to your configuration file. Read [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs-in-tensorflow) for more insight. If you specify your configuration in such a way that an image is included multiple times for the same epoch you will receive the warning message.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem and after a while, I thought out this solution which worked for me but must not be the global solution; if you are using a dataset spread across multiple folders and you are using your own made tf_record converter it might be a problem in a collision of each frame naming across the whole dataset.

Since I used full path as filename (avoided collision) I haven't seen the WARNING anymore. I hope it will help somebody.

```
tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(im_height),
    'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(im_width),
    'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
    'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
    'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
    'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
    'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
    'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
    'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
    'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
    'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
    'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
}))
```

Comment: The reason is that instead of using the hash from the TFrecord, https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/661248a28e9dd0432700b9166bf9c9634b42b711/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_coco_tf_record.py#L176, it creates a new hash based on source_id (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/661248a28e9dd0432700b9166bf9c9634b42b711/research/object_detection/inputs.py#L718), which is in fact image id, which can be repeated when using more than 1 validation datasets. Fix with hash_from_key=tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast(input_dict[fields.InputDataFields.source_id]), HASH_BINS)

Answer (score 0):

If the warnings are still there, then again check your generate_tfrecord.py file. I had changed the tfrecord file for my convenience and there was some bug in it. 
I would suggest just check whether you tfrecord file is correctly showing the ground truth boxes. And then only proceed for training.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the sample issue and yes, after I change the `num_example` to match my validation cases, the error has gone.