# Why is TensorFlow estimator not able to make this simple linear regression prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am learning tensorflow currently and cannot wrap my head around why tensorflow doesn't do proper prediction on following simple regression problem.

X are random numbers from 1000 to 8000
Y is X + 250

So if X is 2000, Y is 2250. This seems like a linear regression problem to me. Yet, when I try making a predictions, it is nowhere near close to what I would expect,  X of 1000 is giving me prediction of 1048 instead of 1250.

Also loss and average loss are huge:

```
{'average_loss': 10269.81, 'loss': 82158.48, 'global_step': 1000}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_data = np.random.randint(1000, 8000, 1000000)
y_true = x_data + 250

feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=[1])]
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feat_cols)

x_train, x_eval, y_train, y_eval = train_test_split(x_data, y_true, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_train}, y_train, batch_size=8, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
train_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_train}, y_train, batch_size=8, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)
eval_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=8, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)

estimator.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=1000)

train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_func, steps=1000)
eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_func, steps=1000)

print(train_metrics)
print(eval_metrics)

brand_new_data = np.array([1000, 2000, 7000])
input_fn_predict = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': brand_new_data}, shuffle=False)

prediction_result = estimator.predict(input_fn=input_fn_predict)

print(list(prediction_result))
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I misinterpreting what LinearRegression means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it does when you tune some hyperparameters. I also changed the optimizer to *AdamOptimizer*.

Mainly the batch size is *1* and epochs is *None*.

> train_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_train}, y_train, batch_size=1, num_epochs=None,
>                                                         shuffle=True)

Code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_data = np.random.randint(1000, 8000, 10000)
y_true = x_data + 250


feat_cols = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x')
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)

estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[feat_cols],optimizer=optimizer)

x_train, x_eval, y_train, y_eval = train_test_split(x_data, y_true, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)


train_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_train}, y_train, batch_size=1, num_epochs=None,
                                                      shuffle=True)

eval_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=1, num_epochs=None,
                                                     shuffle=True)

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_func, steps=1005555)

train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_func, steps=10000)
eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_func, steps=10000)

print(train_metrics)
print(eval_metrics)

brand_new_data = np.array([1000, 2000, 7000])
input_fn_predict = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': brand_new_data}, num_epochs=1,shuffle=False)

prediction_result = estimator.predict(input_fn=input_fn_predict)

for prediction in prediction_result:
    print(prediction['predictions'])
```

Metrics :

> {'average_loss': 3.9024353e-06, 'loss': 3.9024353e-06, 'global_step': 1005555}
>
> {'average_loss': 3.9721594e-06, 'loss': 3.9721594e-06, 'global_step': 1005555}
>
> [1250.003]
>
> [2250.002]
>
> [7249.997]

Comment: Nice, do you care to explain why should epoch size be None and why does it make a difference?

Comment: I tuned the hyperparameters several times as I too was piqued by the problem. And observed that the losses reduced gradually when I increased the steps.A throrough explanation of the calculation is @dmainz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs-in-tensorflow). Try to reduce the steps and change the optimizer to experiment. When I used other optimizers with higher values for batch_size and num_epocs it spewed nan's and I tried to clip the gradients. Didn't work. But finally this is the code that worked.

Comment: If you find any of this useful you could accept or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this slow convergence (you need to train for 1mln. steps, which is weird for such a seeming trivial problem) is that the data is not normalized.

Applying normalization I can train the model to predict the values accurately in 420 steps (I chose 420 because it's the number of memes) to get theses predictions:

```
[1250.387]
[2250.2046]
[7249.2915]
```

Code (done in TF 2.2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_data = np.random.randint(1000, 8000, 1000000)
y_true = x_data + 250

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('size', shape=[1])]
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feat_cols, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01))

def normalize(arr):
    return (arr - arr.mean()) / arr.std()

x_data_norm = normalize(x_data)
y_true_norm = normalize(y_true)

x_train, x_eval, y_train, y_eval = train_test_split(x_data_norm, y_true_norm, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

# numpy_input_fn is for when you have the full dataset available in an array already and want a quick way to do batching/shuffling/repeating
input_func = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'size': x_train}, y_train, batch_size=1, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
train_input_func = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'size': x_train}, y_train, batch_size=1, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
eval_input_func = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'size': x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=1, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

estimator.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=420)

train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_func, steps=500)
eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_func, steps=500)

print(train_metrics)
print(eval_metrics)

# brand_new_data = np.array([1000, 2000, 7000])
# input_fn_predict = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'size': brand_new_data}, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
# prediction_result = estimator.predict(input_fn=input_fn_predict)
# print(list(prediction_result))

# predict w/ normalization
d1 = 1000 
d2 = 2000
d3 = 7000
brand_new_data = np.array([(d1 - x_data.mean()) / x_data.std(), (d2 - x_data.mean()) / x_data.std(), (d3 - x_data.mean()) / x_data.std()])

input_fn_predict = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'size': brand_new_data}, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
prediction_result = estimator.predict(input_fn=input_fn_predict)

for res in prediction_result:
  print(res['predictions'] * y_true.std() + y_true.mean())
```