# ExponentialDecay learning rate schedule with 'staircase=True' changes the training behavior even before it should become effective

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

When adding an [`ExponentialDecay`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/ExponentialDecay) learning rate schedule to my [`Adam`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam) optimizer, it changed the training behavior even before it should become effective. I used the following definition for the schedule:

```py
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    1e-3, decay_steps=25, decay_rate=0.95, staircase=True)
```

Since I'm using `staircase=True`, there should be no difference for the first 25 epochs compared to using a static learning rate of the same value. So the following two optimizers should yield identical training results for the first 25 epochs:

```py
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
```

However I observed that the behavior is different already before:

[image: Example loss curve]

This is the test code I used:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

np.random.seed(0)

x_data = 2*np.random.random(size=(1000, 1))
y_data = np.random.normal(loc=x_data**2, scale=0.05)

lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    1e-3, decay_steps=25, decay_rate=0.95, staircase=True)

histories = []
learning_rates = [1e-3, lr_schedule]
for lr in learning_rates:
    tf.random.set_seed(0)

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        Dense(10, activation='tanh', input_dim=1), Dropout(0.2),
        Dense(10, activation='tanh'), Dropout(0.2),
        Dense(1)
    ])
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')
    history = model.fit(x_data, y_data, epochs=50)
    histories.append(history.history['loss'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel='Epoch', ylabel='Loss')
ax.plot(histories[0], label='Static learning rate')
ax.plot(histories[1], label='Learning rate schedule')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I'm using Python 3.7.9 and the following install of Tensorflow:

```
$ conda list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                2.1.0           mkl_py37h80a91df_0  
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           mkl_py37h6d63fb7_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0              pyhd54b08b_0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `ExponentialDecay`, what you're basically doing is to make a decayed learning rate like:

```py
def decayed_learning_rate(step):
  return initial_learning_rate * decay_rate ^ (step / decay_steps)
```

When you set `staircase=True`, what happens is that `step / decay_steps` is an integer division and the rate follows a staircase function.
Now, let's take a look at the source code:

```py
# ...setup for step function...
global_step_recomp = math_ops.cast(step, dtype) # step is the current step count
p = global_step_recomp / decay_steps
if self.staircase:
  p = math_ops.floor(p)
return math_ops.multiply(initial_learning_rate, math_ops.pow(decay_rate, p), name=name)
```

And we can see that we have a variable `p` that updates at every multiple of `decay_steps`, so at step 25, 50, 75 and so on... Basically, the learning rate is constant for every 25 steps, not epochs - which is why it updates before the first 25 epochs. A good explanation on the difference can be read at [What is the difference between steps and epochs in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 2):

The `decay_steps` paramater in `ExponentialDecay` does not mean number of epochs, but number of steps (training on a single batch). If you want the learning rate to start decaying at 25th epoch, this parameter should be `25 * (num_samples_of_whole_dataset / batch_size)`.