# How to know if tensorflow 2 training is going forward, is stuck or will finish?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

## without gpus

I achieve to start the training process of a simple object detection, using:

- tensorflow 2
- model_main_tf2.py
- pipeline.config: `BATCH_SIZE=16 NUM_CLASSES=1 NUM_STEPS=200000`
- model_main_tf2.py parameters: `NUM_WORKERS=1`
- model: ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8

In the log I saw something like this:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Step 100 per-step time 1.609s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 200 per-step time 1.258s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 300 per-step time 1.253s
...
INFO:tensorflow:Step 800 per-step time 1.257s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 900 per-step time 1.253s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1000 per-step time 1.252s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1100 per-step time 1.247s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1200 per-step time 1.252s
...
INFO:tensorflow:Step 4300 per-step time 1.248s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 4400 per-step time 1.271s
...
INFO:tensorflow:Step 4800 per-step time 1.258s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 4900 per-step time 1.259s
INFO:tensorflow:Step 5000 per-step time 1.251s
...
```

Also each entry of the previous log, shows several parameters:

```
I0119 02:50:17.511021 140379542857536 model_lib_v2.py:708] {
 'Loss/classification_loss': 0.1677758,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.0800046,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.15408026,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.40186065,
 'learning_rate': 0.79281646
}
```

After 12 hours, it never ends. The maximum reached step was **10000**

As I'm not using gpus, so the training step is slow and I don't know when it will end. At least, it is running. I tried the same code with another models and parameters and ends abruptly.

## with gpus

I was able to find a cloud machine with this hardware

```
Tesla V100
2V100.10V
2x NVidia Tesla V100
10 CPU
45GB RAM
32GB GPU RAM
```

With cuda and cudnn successfully installed and these versions:

```
python version: 3.8.10
tensorflow version: 2.7.0
gpu_device_name: /device:GPU:0
Num GPUs Available:  2
Num GPUs Available(exp):  2
```

And I ran my train with these parameters

- tensorflow 2
- model_main_tf2.py
- pipeline.config: `BATCH_SIZE=16 NUM_CLASSES=1 NUM_STEPS=200000`
- model_main_tf2.py parameters: `NUM_WORKERS=2`
- model: ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8

The start time was **10:30:02** and here my annotations:

```
10:38 3800 step
10:40 4500 step
10:43 6300 step
10:46 7700 step
10:52 11000 step
11:00 15100 step
11:13 22500 step
11:28 30700 step
12:00 48000 step
12:15 54400 step
```

And this log in the 54400 step

```
I0129 12:15:10.217693 139823678080832 model_lib_v2.py:708] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.28390533,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.26865262,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 57.277615,
 'Loss/total_loss': 57.83017,
 'learning_rate': 0.0}
```

As we see, with gpus in just 1.5 hours the step **48000** was reached. But it never ends. In the cloud any second is billed, so I need to know **how much longer I have to wait**

## Question

I don't know if the log entry `INFO:tensorflow:Step xyz per-step time 1.251s`, is related to the elapsed time of training process, num_steps parameters or something.

How to know if tensorflow 2 training is going forward, is stuck, or will finish?

## Research:

- [What is the difference between steps and epochs in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs-in-tensorflow)
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping
- https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-to-train-deep-neural-networks-Would-it-be-feasible-for-an-individual-to-replicate-the-performance-of-deep-neural-networks-on-the-MNIST-dataset
- https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet/issues/99

Comment: There's generally an objective function associated with a training model. For example in a classification problem categorical loss is a possible objective function. The concept of going forward, stuck, etc. are generally defined in terms of such function. If the value is improving , e.g., loss is lowering with each passing epoch we could say it is "going forward". In the end this is fairly arbitrary and can be set to anything you want.

Comment: Thanks @MYousefi. I added several loss parameters showed in the log. Do you  know which is related to the loss lowering that you mentioned?

Comment: This should be explained/found somewhere in the model. Is there documentation on it? My first guess would be `Loss/total_loss`

Comment: @JRichardsz I think such a question is more fit on [tf-forum](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TFOD` (`TensorFlow Object Detection`) API then you can limit the total number of steps to be performed from the `config` file. If you are using `SSD Mobilenet` trained on `COCO` dataset, then the `config` file name should be like: [ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config). Here you will find the option:

> Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
> empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
> effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
> never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.

```
num_steps: 200000 # change it accordingly.
```

You may also try [Top-K-Categorical-Accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/TopKCategoricalAccuracy) which will compute how often targets are in the top K predictions *(I am not quite sure if there is an existing API to get it in TFOD, as I didn't use it in TFOD)*. This will give you more insight if it is still worth it to train further. Normally, when we say accuracy, we mean the `Top-1-Accuracy`, that means, we only consider a prediction is correct if the correct class is predicted with highest probability. But in the situations like what you are facing it is important to judge even a slightest change model's performance.

Say, you are working on a classification problem on `10` classes. After completing `100` epochs you got the following predictions on validation set (I am showing the predictions sorted by their `softmax` probabilities):

```
Input Number    Predictions                        Top Prediction   Correct Label
0               (Class_0, Class_2, Class_1, ...)      Class_0         Class_0
1               (Class_1, Class_4, Class_2, ...)      Class_1         Class_2
2               (Class_1, Class_5, Class_2, ...)      Class_1         Class_1
3               (Class_7, Class_3, Class_1, ...)      Class_7         Class_3
....
....
....
```

Say after `150` epochs the predictions on validation set is like this:

```
Input Number    Predictions                        Top Prediction   Correct Label
0               (Class_0, Class_2, Class_1, ...)      Class_0         Class_0
1               (Class_1, Class_2, Class_4, ...)      Class_1         Class_2
2               (Class_1, Class_5, Class_2, ...)      Class_1         Class_1
3               (Class_7, Class_3, Class_1, ...)      Class_7         Class_3
....
....
....
```

If you notice carefully, in the example `1` where the correct label is `Class_2`, in prediction column of that row the correct prediction has come to the second position from the third position. Although in both cases, the top-most prediction is still the same and hence, the ordinary accuracy calculation will give you the same value and you will feel no progress is happening. But with `Top-K-Classification-Accuracy` (typically k = 5) you will be able to know if the time you spend on training will bring you anything meaningful outcome and pull the correct class in the first position.