# In the original T5 paper, what does 'step' mean?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I have been reading the original T5 paper 'Exploring the limits of transfer learning with a unified text-to-text transformer.' On page 11, it says "We pre-train each model for 2^19=524,288 **steps** on C4 before fine-tuning."

I am not sure what the '**steps**' mean. Is it the same as epochs? Or the number of iterations per epoch?

I guess 'steps'='iterations' in a single epoch.

Answer (score 1):

A step is a single training iteration. In a step, the model is given a single batch of training instances. So if the batch size is `128`, then the model is exposed to 128 instances in a single step.

Epochs aren't the same as steps. An epoch is a single pass over an entire training set. So if the training data contains for example 128,000 instances & the batch size is `128`, an epoch amounts to 1,000 steps (128 × 1,000 = 128,000).

The relationship between epochs & steps is related to the size of the training data (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38340311/11858455) for a more detailed comparison). If the data size is changed, then the effective number of steps in an epoch changes as well, (keeping the batch size fixed). So a dataset of 1,280,000 instances would take more steps in an epoch, & vice-versa for a dataset of 12,800 instances.

For this reason, steps are typically reported, especially when it comes to pre-training models on large corpora, because there can be a direct comparison in terms of steps & batch size, which isn't possible (or relatively harder to do) with epochs. So, if someone else wants to compare using an entirely different dataset with a different size, the model would "see" the same number of training instances, if the number of steps & batch size are the same, ensuring that a model isn't unfairly favoured due to training on more instances.

Comment: Clear explanation. I have one more question. The paper does not mention epochs. Is it general for pre-training models not to run on multiple epochs?

Comment: @JetLee My observation is that for pre-training, steps is more commonly reported, yes. This is largely due to the fact that every models tends to be pre-trained on a different corpus, so steps allow for a better comparison as explained. This is in contrast to fine-tuning, where models are typically evaluated on standard datasets, making the training process more easily comparable since the data size is the same. In fact T5 use "a fraction of the entire C4 data set" so they "never repeat any data during pre-training".